# javascript: jQuery replaceWith() not respecting delay()

Tags: javascript, jquery

this is my first post here. I have searched a lot but I haven't found anything regarding this.

I have this little script not working as expected (it runs without errors):

```
(function ($) {
    $("div#replace").click(function () {
        $(this).fadeOut("200").delay("200").replaceWith("<div id='replace'>new content</div>").delay("200").fadeIn("200");
    });
})(jQuery);
```

I was expecting this from div#replace:

> Fade out -> Change content -> Fade in

Instead, I got this behavior:

> Change content -> Fade out -> Fade in

---

**[EDIT]** Thank you guys, I have a solution. I'm posting it here:

I'm using Spokey's approach and I have switched from replaceWith() to html(), which got the fadeIn animation working correctly.

```
$("div#replace").click(function() {
    $(this).fadeOut("200", function() {
        $(this).html("new content").fadeIn("200");
    });
});
```

Thank you! And sorry for my bad english :)

Comment: try with `.html()` instead of `replaceWith()`

Comment: That's why you have `callbacks` to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the fadeOut callback (when fade finished) to replace the div and then show it again.

```
(function ($) {
    $("div#replace").click(function () {
        $(this).fadeOut("200", function(){
            $(this).replaceWith("<div id='replace'>new content</div>").fadeIn("200");
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

[replaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) is not tied to the animation queue, so [delay()](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) will not affect its behavior.

You can, however, use [queue()](http://api.jquery.com/queue/) and [dequeue()](http://api.jquery.com/dequeue/) to tie arbitrary code to the animation queue:

```
$(this).fadeOut("200").delay("200").queue(function(next) {
    $(this).replaceWith("<div id='replace'>new content</div>");
    next();
}).delay("200").fadeIn("200");
```

Note that I use the `next` method provided by `queue()` to signal that the next animation step can start, instead of chaining into `dequeue()` as in my original answer.

That's because `dequeue()` relies on the matched elements, and since `replaceWith()` removes these elements from the DOM I wasn't 100% positive `dequeue()` would work on them.